# wordpress meta query always fails even if data is correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I've following query -

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'accessory',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'accessory-bike',
            'value' => array("33"),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

And now I've this record in database - 
[image]

**520** is the ID for `accessory` post type. It still returns 0 results. I can't figure where the hell did I do wrong ? Stupid wordpress.

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* 
            FROM wp_posts  
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
            ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
            WHERE 1=1  
            AND wp_posts.post_type = 'accessory' 
            AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
            AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'accessory-bike' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) IN ('33') ) )
            GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: It looks like meta_value is `'a:2:{i:0;s:2:"33";i:1;s:2:"61";}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `accessory-bike` on post 520 isn't 33; it's a serialized string.

I can see you're using Advanced Custom Fields so all you need to do is pick a different field type that doesn't save data in a serialized string. You may find that something like a custom taxonomy is more appropriate.

Comment: Yea. I have two options. Either use a custom taxonomy or drop ACF and handle post meta for this particular post type.